# Поиск LIKE в PostgrSQL

Tags: postgresql

```
SELECT * FROM "main_user" WHERE ((UPPER("main_user"."bio"::text) LIKE UPPER('we')))
```

Есть такой код и он находит в ячейке био есть конкретный текст 'we' но есть одна проблема

`bio: 'We'`

`bio: 'We are Family'`

В первом варианте алгоритм его находит но во втором нет

Как мне сделать так чтоб он находил это слово и в ячейке био не с одним а с множеством слов но именно по слову а не по корневой основе

Я знаю что есть %we% но они берут много мусора если будет допустим слово 'wear' он и его возьмет

Comment: А если так попробовать `LIKE UPPER('we %')` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Для того, чтобы найти точное слово "we" в поле bio, можно использовать регулярное выражение. Например, можно использовать следующее выражение:

```
SELECT * FROM "main_user" WHERE ("main_user"."bio"::text ~* '\mwe\M')
```

В этом запросе используется функция ~* (оператор "соответствует регулярному выражению"). Регулярное выражение \mwe\M означает "слово 'we'", где \m означает "начало слова", а \M означает "конец слова".

Помимо этого, можно также использовать функцию split_part() для разбиения текста на слова и поиска нужного слова в массиве слов. Пример запроса может выглядеть так:

```
SELECT * FROM "main_user" WHERE ('we' = any(string_to_array(split_part("main_user"."bio"::text, ' ', 2), ' ')))
```

В этом запросе функция split_part() разбивает текст на слова, разделенные пробелами, а затем преобразует этот массив слов в строку

Comment: а при втором поиске что означает цифра 2?

Comment: @QadyrIsrafilov А самостоятельно посмотреть назначение третьего параметра функции - не? [String Functions and Operators](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/15/functions-string.html)

Comment: Ваш ответ мне очень сильно помог! Спасибо. Но тут появилась проблема их 2. Первая почему он не ищет в кириллице? Второе он не находит если там больше 2х слов, могу привести примеры если хотите